# Shell Commands in C (Error using Execvp)

Tags: c, linux, shell

I want to run the following command "ls | date" but whenever i isolate the ls and the date, they don't execute using execvp.

Problem:

```
Isolated:ls
ls: impossible to acess 'ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': Unknown directory or file
ls: impossible to acess 'ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': Unknown directory or file
Isolated: date
ls: impossible to acess 'date': Unknown directory or file
```

In the code, i want to check the ";" but when i check " " && "|" it isolates the parameters i want... but they don't run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {

 char command_line[256]="ls | date";
 char *ptr_current_command;
 char *saveptr1;
 char *saveptr2;
 char *saveptr3;
 char *ptr_current_parameter;
 char *ptr_current_parameter2;

 char *str[256];
 int i=0;
 int wait_child;
 pid_t pid;



    //Uses Strtok to recognize token ";"     
    ptr_current_command=strtok_r(command_line, ";", &saveptr1);
while (ptr_current_command != NULL) {
    //printf("current_command: %s\n", ptr_current_command);

    //Uses Strtok to recognize token " "
    ptr_current_parameter=strtok_r(ptr_current_command, " ", &saveptr2);
    while(ptr_current_parameter != NULL){
       //printf("\tcurrent_parameter: %s\n", ptr_current_parameter);

       //Uses Strtok to recognize token "|"
       ptr_current_parameter2=strtok_r(ptr_current_parameter, "|", &saveptr3);
       while(ptr_current_parameter2 != NULL){
           printf("\t\tIsolei: %s\n", ptr_current_parameter2);


            str[i]=ptr_current_parameter2;
            i++;           
           //Closes token by token until final NULL of "|"
           ptr_current_parameter2=strtok_r(NULL, "|", &saveptr3);
        }


       pid=fork();
    if (pid < 0) { perror("fork"); exit(errno); }
    if (pid == 0){
        execvp(str[0], str);
        perror("execvp"); exit(errno);
        }   
    if (wait_child)
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);      

       //Fecha Delimitador Espaço
       ptr_current_parameter=strtok_r(NULL, " ", &saveptr2);
         }


    //Closes token by token until final NULL of ";"         
    ptr_current_command=strtok_r(NULL, ";", &saveptr1);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where does this "`impossible to acess`" come from?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: Do you really get "*`acess`*", and not "*`access`*"?

Comment: I had a typo its "access", i am Portuguese so i had to translate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues here.

First, you aren't building `str` correctly.  It has to contain a `NULL` pointer value after the last parameter, otherwise `execvp` won't know which option is the last.

Since `str` is uninitialized, the contents of any element beyond the ones you set in the inner are undefined.  Attempting to read those elements (as `execvp` does) invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

After the inner loop, you need to set the current index to `NULL`.

The second issue is that you don't reset `i` to 0 when entering the inner loop.  So even if the first command works, the second one won't because it keeps writing past the parameters for the first command.

Your inner loop should look like this after the fix:

```
   i = 0;   // reset i for each command
   while(ptr_current_parameter2 != NULL){
       printf("\t\tIsolei: %s\n", ptr_current_parameter2);


        str[i]=ptr_current_parameter2;
        i++;           
       //Closes token by token until final NULL of "|"
       ptr_current_parameter2=strtok_r(NULL, "|", &saveptr3);
    }
    str[i] = NULL;  // terminate the list
```

Comment: Ok i understand now what my problems where but i come up with a different problem... Problem: Can't access ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Comment: @Anomime Are you able to successfully run `ls` on the command line by itself?

Comment: No when i compile and run it gives me the error of ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 can't access. I compile like this: gcc <file>.c -o <some name>

Comment: @Anomime Not from your program, from the shell.  If you run `ls` from the shell, does it work?

Comment: Found out the error.. It didn't give me access because it didn't know where to go i forgot to put str[i]=NULL in the first